# tar -: cannot stat: No such file or directory

Tags: tar

I'm trying to write a backup script, using the method from [this answer from superuser](https://superuser.com/a/665181) to show a progress bar.

I invoke `tar` like this:

```bash
tar cf --exclude-vcs --exclude-ignore=.tarignore - $backup_files -P | pv -s $(du -csb $backup_files |awk '{print $1}'|tail -n 1)  | gzip > "$target_file"
```

What I'm getting is the error message "tar -: Can not stat: No such file or directory" but the script keeps running. What exactly is going on here? Why is tar not iterpreting `-` as "use stdout instead of an output file"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was that tar the `f` flag means *the next argument* is interpreted as a filename, rather than the first file operand [like an older document](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xcu/tar.html) suggested. I found a file in my working directory named `--exclude-vcs`.

The correct order of arguments is

```
tar cf - --exclude-vcs --exclude-ignore=.tarignore $backup_files -P
```

I'm not sure why the script didn't exit when tar did.

Comment: Since you resolved your issue, please don't forget to accept your own answer so it doesn't pop up as "Unanswered" somewhere down the line.

Comment: I would bet tar didn't exit as `-` further away in command line mean : read stdin, just hitting CTRL-D should have done the job.

Comment: @Archemar, it interprets the `-` as the name of a file to store in the archive, hence the error. As in `echo foo > ./-; tar cf foo.tar -` stores a file called `-`. The dash means stdin/stdout only as an argument to `f`/`-f`... The script doesn't exit because there's no reason to. Even if `tar` there fails, the pipeline as a whole finishes fine. You'd need `set -o pipefail` to have it otherwise (and `set -e`).

Comment: @haem note that that document knows nothing about dashed options, so for that tar, ` --exclude-vcs` would seem to be the first file operand...